# How to send and get data using firebase functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I would like to create firebase functions that receives data as params just like expressjs, but id need a bodyParser.

I have already tried to implement expressJs into my firebase but I couldn't do it successfully.

Is it possible to get data from the frontend as json and use on my firebase functions? How?

I would like to do something like this:

```
exports.someFirebaseFunction = ((req, res) => { ... do something with req.params.userName etc... });
```

and on my frontend send data using fetch api as object or json. please help :c

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to trigger firebase function through an HTTP request.

Ex,

```
exports.someFirebaseFunction = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

  ... do something with req.params.userName etc...

  // Always end an HTTP function with send(), redirect(), or end()

  res.status(200).send(data);
});
```

For more info about triggering, reading request data, etc refer their official doc

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events